# parallel lapply with random generation

Tags: r, parallel-processing

What is the best way to translate the following function to parallel processing?

```
myapply <- function(n, FUN, ...) {
  lapply(1:n, function(i) { FUN(...) })
}
```

I need to run it with other functions used for random generation, e.g.

```
myapply(100, function(...) rnorm(100, ...), 1, 1)
```

so I need it to correctly handle random seeds. Moreover, I want the code to be portable and platform-independent, so `parallel::mcapply` does not work for me. I was considering `foreach` with `doParallel` and `doRNG`, but `doRNG` currently is not available for Windows on CRAN and was not updated for three years! I considered `parallel::parLapply`, but I have problems with properly doing `clusterExport` since I do not have a closed list of elements to export (I found [this implementation](https://www.r-bloggers.com/implementing-mclapply-on-windows-a-primer-on-embarrassingly-parallel-computation-on-multicore-systems-with-r/), or [here](https://github.com/nathanvan/parallelsugar/blob/master/R/mclapply_socket.R), but I hoped for something simpler).

Comment: You might be able to use the [`future`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future/index.html) package: the [NEWS](https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/blob/1b93c3425e290971712c8f220f9a63ac67fdadc0/NEWS#L34-L44) file talks about reproducibility with parallel RNG use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `future_lapply()` function of the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (I'm the author) provides parallel RNGs using L'Ecuyer-CMRG RNG streams, which is also what `parallel::mclapply()` uses.  It works the same across all OSes and regardless of parallel backend.

The following works on all OSes, including Windows:

```
myapply <- function(n, FUN, ...) {
  future_lapply(1:n, function(i, ...) { 
    FUN(...)
  }, ..., future.seed = TRUE)
}

library("future")
plan(multiprocess)

y <- myapply(100, function(...) rnorm(100, ...), mean = 1, sd = 1)
```

Comment: This is marvelous! I heard about the future, but didn't have time to familiarize with it -- it seems that the time has come for the future :)